# AngularJS trailing slash with parameter

Tags: angularjs

My angularJS apps base URL is: `/app/`

However when people visit `/app?hello=123` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

When people visit `/app/?hello=123` it works as expected

Visiting `/app` redirects to `/app/` however not when there are parameters `/app?hello=1`

Any idea how to make it work? i assume i need to some how redirect users from /app?hello=123 to /app/?hello=123 before the angular loads.

I would like to do this client side not server side.

Comment: probably people should visit `/app/?hello=123`

Comment: There's a lot of missing info here that makes it difficult to answer this question.  

1.  Does the app work when at the base URL of '/app/'?
2.  What are you seeing when the app "does not run" when including the query string of "?hello=123" - an error message?  Do you have routing configured properly to accept a query string of hello?

Comment: by the way, as my previous answer was short - there's a huge difference between `/app?hello=123` and `/app/?hello=123`

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski i would like both to work. i work like angularJS to switch /app?hello=123 to /app/?hello=123 so that the app works